# Print last match of a sed regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following:

```
cat /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855 | sed -n '/Starting inject/s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p
```

Which gives a list of

```
0
1
2
..
```

How can I print only the last match with this sed?

Thanks.

Comment: Add `| tail -1` would do it

Comment: I know about tail. I'd like to use as little commands as possible.

Comment: Clarity trumps brevity. `;h}{x;p}` is exactly the same number of characters as `|tail -1`, but I know which I find easier to read.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I'm also here to learn :)

Comment: We are all here to learn! So learn two things: (1) there is a clever trick to achieve this using only `sed` commands - see accepted answer; and (2) I recommend that you don't do that "in real life" unless you have a compelling reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the substitution results in the hold buffer then print it at the end:

```
sed -ne '

/Starting inject/ {
    # do the substitution
    s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/

    # instead of printing, copy the results to the hold buffer
    h
}

$ { # at the end of the file:
    # copy the hold buffer back to the pattern buffer
    x
    # print the pattern buffer
    p
}

' /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855
```

Comment: Works!
`# sed -ne '/Starting inject/{s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/;h};${x;p}' /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855
`

Answer (score 1):

Use `tac` to print the file in reverse (first line last) and exit after first match:

```
tac /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855 | sed -n '/Starting inject/s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p;q'
```

Last part is where we have `;q` to quit:

```
sed -n '....p;q'
              ^
```

#### Example

Print last number:

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

$ tac a | sed -n 's/\([0-9]\)/\1/p;q' 
9
```

Comment: Should work in theory, but not for me:
# tac /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855 | sed -n '/Starting inject/s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
# tac /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855 | sed -n '/Starting inject/s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p;q'
<nothing printed>

Comment: Strange... but `tac` works to you, right? Also, I think you missed the `\(` and `\)` to catch `[0-9]*` (you are only using `[0-9]*`, is if you had the `-r` mode on)

Comment: No. It's there. I guess the comment stripped it out.
`# tac /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855 | sed -n '/Starting inject/s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
`

`# tac /tmp/cluster_concurrentnodedump.out.20140501.103855 | sed -n '/Starting inject/s/.*[Ii]nject \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p;q'
`

Comment: Looks weird. It is better if you update your question providing a sample file so we can "play" with it. Also if you indicate the OS you are using and sed version.

Comment: I always forget about `tac` - `cat` in reverse.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga) ; GNU sed version 4.1.5

The log itself is really long. But I'm mostly interested in lines that look like this:
`20140501 10:39:33 Starting inject 1 of 99999
20140501 11:09:33 Starting inject 2 of 99999
20140501 14:46:09 Starting inject 1 for node node2:0:2:50050768020023B7, iteration 1  [Inject 1]
20140501 15:06:09 Starting inject 2 for node node1:0:1:50050768020023B6, iteration 1  [Inject 2]

`

Comment: @Maxim_united well I see you already solved your issue with the other answer. For next times, keep in mind that code does not show properly in comments, it is better to update the question.